# Primary Key Constraint, migration of table from local db to snowflake, recommended data types for json column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What order can I copy data into two different tables to comply with the table constraints I created locally?

I created an example from the documentation, but was hoping to get recommendations on how to optimize the data stored by selecting the right types.

I created two tables, one was the list of names and the second is a list of names with a date they did something.

```html
create or replace table name_key (
    id integer not null,
    id_sub integer not null,
    constraint pkey_1 primary key (id, id_sub) not enforced,
    name varchar
    );
create or replace table recipts (
    col_a integer not null,
    col_b integer not null,
    constraint fkey_1 foreign key (col_a, col_b) references name_key (id, id_sub) not enforced,
    recipt_date datetime,
    did_stuff variant
    );

Insert into name_key values (0, 0, 'Geinie'), (1, 1, 'Greg'), (2,2, 'Alex'), (3,3, 'Willow'); 
Insert into recipts values(0,0, Current_date()), (1,1, Current_date()), (2,2, Current_date()), (3,3, Current_date());

Select * from name_key;
Select * from recipts;

Select * from name_key
join recipts on name_key.id = recipts.col_a
where id = 0 or col_b = 2;
```

I read: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/table-considerations.html#storing-semi-structured-data-in-a-variant-column-vs-flattening-the-nested-structure where it recommends to change timestamps from strings to a variant. I did not include the fourth column, I left it blank for future use. Essentially it captures data in json format, so I made it a variant. Would it be better to rethink this table structure to flatten the variant column?

Also I would like to change the key to AUTO_INCRDEMENT, is there something like this in Snowflake?

Comment: You've got 3 or 4 independent questions/topics here. Some of which have been answered before. This makes it hard to ask follow ups and respond to any of them in a useful way. I'd suggest narrowing this down to a single question, and make multiple posts if really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What order can I copy data into two different tables to comply with the table constraints I created locally?

You need to give more context about your constraints, but you can control the order of copy statements. For foreign keys generally you want to load the table that is referenced before the table that does the referencing.

> where it recommends to change timestamps from strings to a variant.

I think you misread that documentation. It recommends extracting values from a variant column into their own separate columns (in this case a timestamp column), ESPECIALLY if those columns are dates and times, arrays, and numbers within strings.

Converting a timestamp column to a variant, is exactly what it is recommending against.

> Would it be better to rethink this table structure to flatten the variant column?

It's definitely good to think carefully about, and do performance tests on, situations where you are using semi-structured data, but without more information on your specific situation and data, it's hard to say.

> Also I would like to change the key to AUTO_INCRDEMENT, is there something like this in Snowflake?

Yes Snowflake has an [Auto_increment feature](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters). Although I've heard this has some issue with [working with COPY INTO Statements](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-copy-into-a-table-with-an-auto-increment-column)